# VB.net DataSet to Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dataset, datasource

I want my DataSet query results to be transferred to an array.

Here is my query:

[image]

This is the only way I know to display the contents of my query:
**Trans_TableTableAdapter.SelectDistinct(DBDataSet.Trans_Table)**

My problem is I don't know how to apply this query to an array.

This is the last piece of my puzzle, I really need help to complete my project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This contains many columns with different data-types, what kind of array do you think of? Also, a `DataTable` typically contains multiple rows and every row has multiple columns. Do you want a `List(Of Object())`?

Comment: my query only retrieves one column, the highlighted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a `String()` from the query that returns a single column? You can use LINQ:

```
Dim accounts As String() = DBDataSet.Trans_Table.AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Account")).
    ToArray()
```

If you prefer query syntax:

```
Dim accounts = From row In DBDataSet.Trans_Table.AsEnumerable()
               Select row.Field(Of String)("Account")
Dim accountArray As String() = accounts.ToArray()
```

Since that seems to be a strongly typed `DataSet` there should be a named column which you can use directly:

```
Dim accounts = From row In DBDataSet.Trans_Table Select row.Account
Dim accountArray As String() = accounts.ToArray()
```

Comment: i want to use my distinct query is it possible? my Account column has duplicates, i want to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: @MarcIntes: Yes of course. You just need to execute the available method as you've already done: `Trans_TableTableAdapter.SelectDistinct(DBDataSet.Trans_Table)`. After this line you can use my code above.